# NSFetchedresultscontroller with tableview inserting new section crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm working on messages app and all message I save in core data. I use NSFetchedResultsController with tableView to show them on the screen. I have section in my nsfetchedResultsController which are week's days. I mean that one section is for example Today another one is for example yesterday. When I would like to add new message which should be inserted to new section I got crash when I try insert new object to core data which generate new section in tableview. Here is log which I got :

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (12) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (8), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)

**AND HERE IS MY CODE FOR NSFETCHRESULTSCONTROLLER DELEGATE**

```
- (void)dataLoaderDidChangeContent:(GISingleConversationDataLoader *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    if (_shouldScrollToBottomAfterUpdate) {
        [self scrollToBottomAnimated:NO];
    }
}

- (void)dataLoaderWillChangeContent:(GISingleConversationDataLoader *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)dataLoader:(GISingleConversationDataLoader *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            if ([self.tableView numberOfSections]) {
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
            } else {
                [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            }
            _shouldScrollToBottomAfterUpdate = YES;
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;
    }
}
```

**DATA SOURCE :**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.dataProvider.fetchedResultsController.sections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([[self.dataProvider.fetchedResultsController sections] count] < 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.dataProvider.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    GICDChatMessage *message = [self _messageAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    GIChatMessageType type = [message.type integerValue];

    NSString *kMessageTypeKey = [message isOutgoing] ? kOutgoingMessageKey : kIncomingMessageKey;
    NSString *CellIdentifier;  CellIdentifier = self.cellIdentifiers[@(type)][kMessageTypeKey];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.configureCellBlock(cell, message, indexPath);

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:tableView.backgroundColor];

    return cell;
}
```

I create NSFetchedResultsController and I manage him in my data loader. I created it to make my viewController lighter.

**Here is my Data loader implementation:**

```
- (id)initWithConversation:(GIConversation *)conversation delegate:(id<GISingleConversationDataLoaderProtocol>)delegate {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _conversation = conversation;
        _delegate = delegate;
        [self resultsController];
        [_fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];
        [self performFetch];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSPredicate *)predicate {
    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"conversationJid == %@", _conversation.jid];
}

- (NSString *)entityName {
    return @"GICDChatMessage";
}

- (NSArray *)sortDescriptors {
    return @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"receivedAt" ascending:YES]];
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController*)resultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController == nil) {
        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:[self fetchRequest] managedObjectContext:[self context] sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionNameKeyPath" cacheName:nil];
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

-(void)performFetch {
    if (_fetchedResultsController) {
        [_fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
        [_delegate dataLoaderDidChangeContent:self];
    }
}


- (NSFetchRequest*)fetchRequest {

    NSFetchRequest *result = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[self entityName]];

    NSPredicate *mainPredicate = [self predicate];
    result.predicate = mainPredicate;
    result.sortDescriptors = [self sortDescriptors];

    return result;
}
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    return [[GICoreDataManager sharedInstance] mainContext];
}

#pragma mark - fetch change

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    [_delegate dataLoader:self
          didChangeObject:anObject
              atIndexPath:indexPath
            forChangeType:type
             newIndexPath:newIndexPath];
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [_delegate dataLoaderWillChangeContent:self];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [_delegate dataLoaderDidChangeContent:self];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    [_delegate dataLoader:self didChangeSection:sectionInfo atIndex:sectionIndex forChangeType:type];
}
```

`> sectionNameKeyPath` is a key which is define in my model class category and looks: :

```
- (NSString *)sectionNameKeyPath {

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [self.receivedAt timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSString *string = [[GICDChatMessage timeIntervalFormatter] stringForTimeInterval:roundf(timeInterval / oneDayTimeInterval) * oneDayTimeInterval];

    if ([string isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"just now", nil)]) {
        string = NSLocalizedString(@"Today", nil);
    }

    return string;
}
```

It just sort messages for each days.

Do you know what caused this problem or what I'm doing wrong?

My English is not good so if you don't understand what I mean please ask me and I will try to explain more clearly.

Comment: Can we also see the datasource methods for the tableview?  I suspect it's out of sync with the fetched results controller.

Comment: Since these methods are pretty much boilerplate straight out of the Reference (as they should be, no reason to change them really), the dataSource methods are the next likely candidate.

Comment: The NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert case is not the boilerplate code, is there any reason for that? And what about the controller:didChangeSection: delegate method, is that also implemented?

Comment: Here you are my data source :) No, I don't implement DidChangeSection. Should I?

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement didChangeSection:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
    atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

EDIT also you will need to remove the part of your code where you manage sections:

```
   if ([self.tableView numberOfSections]) {
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    } else {
        [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
```

Comment: I add didChangeSection but I still have the same problem :/

Comment: I added DidChangeSection and Yes problem with section is solved but now it is stopped here`[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];` and it doesn't want to go further :/

Comment: Did you get rid of the part where you do this:             if ([self.tableView numberOfSections]) {
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
            } else {
                [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            }
?

Comment: I removed it and I have the same problem but with rows now

Comment: This is boilerplate NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate code, you can find the whole thing here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks!  I had a similar problem and had forgotten or overlooked the didChangeSection:

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented any of the methods of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol. Instead you've written custom methods with similar name. For example, here's on of the methods you posted:

```
- (void)dataLoaderWillChangeContent:(GISingleConversationDataLoader *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}
```

Although the name of the above method is similar to a method of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol, it's not the same method, and therefore will never be called by your fetched results controller. Here's the declaration of the method you would need to implement if you want the fetched results controller to call it:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller;
```

Similarly, you should change the names and signatures of the other methods in that section of your code to match the actual API provided by Core Data.

Comment: These methods are implemented in my dataProvider

Comment: @user3533403 If that's the case, you need to edit your question to provide a more accurate picture of your implementation, including the methods that *actually* implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol. You should also explain the design of your 'data loader', whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

**Aggregate the updates**

Then in `controllerDidChangeContent` you need to process all received updates and forward to the `UITableView`

This code works perfect for me:

```
class SomeVC: UITableViewController {

        /* ... */

// Add properties for each expected update type

    var insertedSectionIndexes = NSMutableIndexSet()
    var deletedSectionIndexes  = NSMutableIndexSet()

    var deletedRowIndexPaths:  Set<NSIndexPath> = []
    var insertedRowIndexPaths: Set<NSIndexPath> = []
    var updatedRowIndexPaths:  Set<NSIndexPath> = []
}



extension SomeVC: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    func controllerWillChangeContent (controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {}

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeObject anObject: NSManagedObject,
        atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
        newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
            switch type {
            case .Insert: insertedRowIndexPaths.insert(indexPath!)
            case .Update: updatedRowIndexPaths.insert(indexPath!)
            case .Move:
                if newIndexPath?.section != indexPath?.section {
                    insertedRowIndexPaths.insert(newIndexPath!)
                    deletedRowIndexPaths.insert(indexPath!)
                }
            case .Delete: deletedRowIndexPaths.insert(indexPath!)
            }
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo,
        atIndex sectionIndex: Int,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch type {
        case .Insert: insertedSectionIndexes.addIndex(sectionIndex)
        case .Delete: deletedSectionIndexes.addIndex(sectionIndex)
        default:()
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent (controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

        tableView?.beginUpdates()

        tableView?.deleteSections(deletedSectionIndexes, withRowAnimation: .None)
        tableView?.insertSections(insertedSectionIndexes, withRowAnimation: .None)

        updatedRowIndexPaths.subtractInPlace(deletedRowIndexPaths)
        updatedRowIndexPaths.subtractInPlace(insertedRowIndexPaths)

        tableView?.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(Array(deletedRowIndexPaths), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView?.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(Array(insertedRowIndexPaths), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView?.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(Array(updatedRowIndexPaths), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

        tableView?.endUpdates()
        // Do not forget to clean up!
        insertedSectionIndexes.removeAllIndexes()
        deletedSectionIndexes.removeAllIndexes()
        deletedRowIndexPaths = []
        insertedRowIndexPaths = []
        updatedRowIndexPaths = []
    }

}
```

**Note: that code from Xcode 7 beta 2, some methods might be called different**